# PrimeNG Table: Programmatically handle row editing (pSaveEditableRow)

Tags: html, angular, row, primeng

I'm using a PrimeNG Table, and I would like to handle saving row editing programmatically in the case that there are any custom validation errors that need to be addressed beforehand in edit mode. Currently, I have added pSaveEditableRow to a button, which on click, ends row editing and saves edits made to the row. I need to override this and do some validation beforehand. How can this be accomplished?

I've looked into the documentation for PrimeNG, and it looks like I may be able to call the 'saveRowEdit' function, but I need to pass rowData and rowElement, both of which come from pEditableRow, and pEditableRow appears to be set to an object with properties needed for the table.

References:
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/b3e7b3582f98936e0cddcafc921c61a9eabf9bcd/src/app/components/table/table.ts#L1883

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/b3e7b3582f98936e0cddcafc921c61a9eabf9bcd/src/app/components/table/table.ts#L3807

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For those who want to end edit mode on a row manually, I've found a solution:

1. Remove `pSaveEditableRow` from your `button` tag (if you have added it). [As the documentation states](https://primeng.org/table), `pSaveEditableRow` simply switches the row back to view mode.
2. Add `#htmlTableRowElement` to your `<tr>` tag: `<tr [pEditableRow]="rowData" #htmlTableRowElement>...</tr>`
3. Pass `rowData` and `htmlTableRowElement` in to the `(click)` function on the `button` tag.
4. Add `import { Table } from 'primeng/table'` to your component.
5. Add `@ViewChild('dt', { static: false }) table: Table` to your component.
6. Add `#dt` to your `<p-table>`: `<p-table #dt>...</p-table>`
7. You can now call `this.table.saveRowEdit(rowData, htmlTableRowElement)` in your function which is invoked on button click. This will end edit mode for the row and put it into view mode. `rowData` is a type of any (an object containing your row data), and `htmlTableRowElement` is pretty self-explanatory.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This was extremely helpful. I wish there was a cleaner way achieve this using pSaveEditableRow and without having to hack into the internal method, but your solution works like a charm.

Comment: @tb517 Thanks a lot, I really needed this! Just curious, what's the best way to provide error to each column?

Comment: @J4N you can use Reactive Forms for this purpose and define a formGroup at tr level and each cell would have its formControl. This way you can later check for add some additional logic for example only if form is valid, submit the edited row, otherwise, highlight errors and remain in Editable Row mode.

Comment: @tb517 Thanks really appreciate that you found a solution and came back to describe. It was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://primefaces.org/primeng/table/edit), in the second example, you notice there are 3 buttons, each bound to a different function:

```html
<button *ngIf="!editing" pButton pRipple type="button" pInitEditableRow icon="pi pi-pencil" (click)="onRowEditInit(product)" class="p-button-rounded p-button-text"></button>
<button *ngIf="editing" pButton pRipple type="button" pSaveEditableRow icon="pi pi-check" (click)="onRowEditSave(product)" class="p-button-rounded p-button-text p-button-success mr-2"></button>
<button *ngIf="editing" pButton pRipple type="button" pCancelEditableRow icon="pi pi-times" (click)="onRowEditCancel(product, ri)" class="p-button-rounded p-button-text p-button-danger"></button>
```

It seems to me that, between these 3 options, you should be able to accomplish whatever you need to. From your requirements, as the user clicks on the check mark button to save, you would execute your validation logic and either proceed with the save, or notify the user that one-to-many of the fields in the row are incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, adding pSaveEditableRow to the button takes the row out of edit mode on click. In short, I am looking for a way to take the row out of edit mode programmatically.

Comment: In that case, there is also a pCancelEditableRow button which you could maintain a reference to (via a @View/@ContentChildren), and then you could pass the index of the row up in order to find that particular reference in the query list, and then `elementRef.nativeElement.click()` on that.